# How do I set the filters to only apply to a particular graph and not the whole dataset?

Tags: microstrategy

I'm working on a dossier and I have a dataset that includes customer types. I want to be able to make one graph that shows only customer types A, B and C, and a second graph on the same page that shows only customer type D. However, once I apply the filter to one of them, it applies automatically to both (because they’re created from the same dataset). Do you have any advice on how I could fix that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with **not** having the filter on the Filter Panel, you can add filters directly on the chapter and then target which visualizations the filter should apply to.

[screenshot of how to "Select Targets" in MicroStrategy to choose what viz to filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVdEa.png)